# Appending hyperlinks to JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane, styleddocument

I've got a program outputs some URLs to a JEditorPane. I want the URLs to be hyperlinks. The program will basically output the URLS to the JEditorPane as if it were a log.

I've got it somewhat working, but it's not hyperlinking the URLs.

Here's the code I have:

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
editorPane.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
editorPane.setEditable(false);
editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
    //listener code here
});

//some other code here

StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) editorPane.getDocument();

String url = "http://some url";
String newUrl = "\n<a href=\""+url+"\">"+url+"</a>\n";
document.insertString(document.getLength(), "\n" + newUrl + "\n", null);
```

Instead of http://example.com/ it's outputting:

`<a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a>`

If I don't use a StyledDocument and just do `editorPane.setText(newUrl)` it does correctly hyperlink the URLs, but it has the obvious problem that setText will replace whatever was already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `editorPane.setText()`, the method will use the editor kit to insert the string. That means it will analyze it, style it and then use `document.insertString()` with the appropriate styles to create the expected effect.

If you call `document.insertString()` directly, you're circumventing the editor kit -> no styling. Have a look at the source code for `setText()` to see how it's done: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/JEditorPane.java#JEditorPane.setText%28java.lang.String%29

Because of copyright, I can't copy the code here. This should get you started:

```
Document doc = editorPane.getDocument();
EditorKit kit = editorPane.getEditorKit();
StringReader r = new StringReader(newUrl);
kit.read(r, doc, doc.getLength());
```